Why is textattributes(textattrs) not working in my SAS barchart with segments?
In the graph the numbers in the segments is just shown in black.
proc template;
  define statgraph barchart;
    begingraph ;
      discreteattrmap name="farger";
       value "Asia"   / fillattrs=(color=darkgreen) textattrs=(color=white);
       value "USA" / fillattrs=(color=white) textattrs=(color=green);
       value "Europe" / fillattrs=(color=red) textattrs=(color=blue);
     enddiscreteattrmap;
     discreteattrvar attrvar=origin var=origin attrmap="farger";

     entrytitle "Freq of Total Models by Type and Origin";

     layout overlay;
        barchart x=type / name="carmodels"
          stat=freq display=all
          group=origin
          barlabel=true
          groupdisplay=Stack 
          segmentlabel=true; 
        discretelegend "carmodels";
      endlayout;
    endgraph;
  end;
run;
%stpbegin;
proc sgrender data=SASHELP.cars template=barchart;
run;

Show example graph:
In the graph the segments the numbers should have been in the color set in the textattrs in my discreteattrmap but is just shown in black.

According to the documentation for DISCRETEATTRMAP, the TEXTATTRS option would be ignored in a BARCHART statement.

TEXTATTRS=style-element | style-element (text-options)| (text-options)
specifies the text attributes to use when an attribute map is applied to text in a graph.
Default: The GraphDataText style element.
Restriction: This option is honored only by the TEXTGROUP= option in the AXISTABLE statement and the GROUP= option in the TEXTPLOT statement.


Thanxs it saved me some time. I´ll try to fix it with a annotated data set.
